# Encountering Errors with EIA Packages in R: Seeking Solutions

Tags: r

I'm not sure why this package is not working in R.

```
library(eia)
eia_key = "YourKey"
eia_set_key(eia_key)
eia_cats()
```

The resulting error is:

Error: Page not found

I have also tried the package:

```
library(EIAapi)
api_key <- Sys.getenv("myKey")

df2 <- eia_get(
  api_key = api_key,
  api_path = "electricity/rto/fuel-type-data/data/",
  data = "value",
  format = "data.table"
)

df2
```

Resulting in the error:
Error in eia_get(api_key = "myKey", :
Could not pull the data... ❌
Check the query parameters (e.g., api key, path, etc.) or the error log

Do you know why either of these codes isn't working?

Sources:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eia/vignettes/eia.html

https://github.com/RamiKrispin/EIAapi